# Why does overriding change column names

Tags: hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

I was using the default implementation of the rev listener and as expected the columns in my REVINFO table were: revtstmp and rev.

However, when I overrode the default - all I did was:

```
... MyRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity
```

those column names were changed to "timestamp" and "id".

Anyone know why?

Using envers 4.1.5_Final...

** EDIT **
As no one has yet answered, I am adding more information.

The Adam Warski authored "DefaultRevisionEntity" class defines only two members:
    private int id;

and 
    private long timestamp;

Thus, I understand that when I extend that class, those will be the column names that I should expect.  However, the "baffling" question is: why was it that when I did NOT extend the default, the columns were different (rev and revtstmp respectively) and also what the documentation said?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because when you don't extend, Envers uses a default configuration that has those column names hardcoded, e.g. they don't originate from the entity class's metadata.  When you extend the `DefaultRevisionEntity`, Envers defaults to using standard ORM naming strategies.

More technically speaking, `RevisionInfoConfiguration` is the culprit here.

As a part of the bootstrap of Envers, the `#configure()` method of this class is called and it searches the defined entities for a custom revision entity implementation.  If an implementation is detected, Envers basically maps the class like any other entity.

But if no custom implementation is detected, `generateDefaultRevisionInfoXmlMapping` is called which will automatically build the appropriate XML structure, which uses hard-coded column names for the `@RevisionNumber` and `@RevisionTimestamp` annotated fields; ergo you get the columns named `REV` and `REVTSTMP`.

I've registered a JIRA issue [HHH-11325](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11325) to address the improvement.